# Flex display:flex; flex: 0 1 33.333%; in mobile screen does not work

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I must make block__item
I have html and css styles for html.
Output must be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvpcm.png

```css
   *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        min-height: auto;
        background-color: red;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
            
    .container {
        max-width: 1200px;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: green;
        padding: 0 15px;
    }

    @media (max-width: 1200px) {
        .container{
            width: 970px;
        }
    }
    @media (max-width: 992px) {
        .container{
            width: 750px;
        }
    }
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .container{
            width: none;
        }
    }

    .block {
        margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    }

    .block__row {
        display: flex;
        margin: 0 -15px;
    }
    .block__column {
        flex: 0 1 33.333%;
        padding: 0 15px;
    } 
    
    .block__item {
        background-color: aqua;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .block__img {
        background-color: yellow;
        padding: 0 0 60% 0;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .block__txt {
        font-size: 24px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 15px 15px;
    }
One requirement is we must not change code inside media queries for solving this problem.
Below you can see styles for css.
Also here are css styles as snippet:
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="block">
                <div class="block__row">
                    <div class="block__column">
                        <div class="block__item">
                            <div class="block__img"></div>
                            <div class="block__txt">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni,
                                expedita.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, expedita.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block__column">
                        <div class="block__item">
                            <div class="block__img"></div>
                            <div class="block__txt">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni,
                                expedita.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, expedita.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block__column">
                        <div class="block__item">
                            <div class="block__img"></div>
                            <div class="block__txt">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni,
                                expedita.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, expedita.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
=
```

Maybe flex must be flex: 1 0 33.33% for solving this problem?
Please help!

Thank You !

Comment: Please improve your description of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are trying to stack the items on top of each other in mobile view?? If so, you can do so by setting the `flex-direction:column` inside the media query for max-width of mobile.

Comment: @Ali Mustafa Can we do it without writing flex-direction:column in media queries?

Comment: Please check my answer. Yes, you can. You can use `flex:wrap` on the parent container. Now as soon as the size of screen shrinks, the items will stack on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex-wrap property to achieve this. As soon as the screen reaches mobile size, the items will stack on top of each other.

```css
*{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        min-height: auto;
        background-color: red;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
            
    .container {
        max-width: 1200px;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: green;
        padding: 0 15px;
    }

    @media (max-width: 1200px) {
        .container{
            width: 970px;
        }
    }
    @media (max-width: 992px) {
        .container{
            width: 750px;
        }
    }
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .container{
            width: none;
        }
    }

    .block {
        margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    }

    .block__row {
        display: flex;
        margin: 0 -15px;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .block__column {
        flex: 0 1 auto;
        padding: 0 15px;
    } 
    
    .block__item {
        background-color: aqua;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .block__img {
        background-color: yellow;
        padding: 0 0 60% 0;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .block__txt {
        font-size: 24px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 15px 15px;
    }
One requirement is we must not change code inside media queries for solving this problem.
Below you can see styles for css.
Also here are css styles as snippet:
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="block">
                <div class="block__row">
                    <div class="block__column">
                        <div class="block__item">
                            <div class="block__img"></div>
                            <div class="block__txt">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni,
                                expedita.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, expedita.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block__column">
                        <div class="block__item">
                            <div class="block__img"></div>
                            <div class="block__txt">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni,
                                expedita.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, expedita.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block__column">
                        <div class="block__item">
                            <div class="block__img"></div>
                            <div class="block__txt">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni,
                                expedita.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, expedita.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
=
```

Comment: Did You see the result of Your code?)))

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I think that your problem can be solved by wrapping all the items but for that to happen the container needs to be responsive. You need to figure out why the container that contains all the items is not shrinking with the screen size. Once it starts shrinking all the elements in it will wrap one by one as the screen goes small.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flex Box</title>
    <style>
        .three {
            /* width: 100%; */
            padding: 15px;
            flex-basis: 100%;
            background-color: blue;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .three div {
            flex-basis: 30%;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: gray;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <section class="three">
        <div class="threeFlexOne">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="threeFlexTwo">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="threeFlexThree">
            3
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

You must try this piece of code where i have a main div 3 inside of which there are 3 subdive and on main div i applied flex and `flex-wrap: wrap;` which does the work for me soo for you!